# How to avoid jquery .click() event spam

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, click, spam

I want to know how to protect the jQuery .click() (or whatever) event to spawm.
I creat a project file in JSFiddle, you can set it above. If you can always click in the `<body>` the next `<li>` item always get the `.curr-str` class, but the animation isn't finished.

I try this:

```
    if($('body').is(':animated'){
alert("animate is progress, wait");
}
```

but it's not working...

The test code:

HTML:

```
<div class="list">

    <ul>
        <li class="curr-str">JavaScript</li>
         <li>JavaScript</li>
         <li>JavaScript</li>
         <li>JavaScript</li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.curr-str{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$( 'body' ).click(function() {
    $current = $(".curr-str");
  $( $current ).next('li').addClass('curr-str').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em0ahdsy/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.click()` and re-register the event handler in the complete callback of [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete)

```js
$(function () {
    var body = $("body");
  
    body.one("click", removeListElement);

    function removeListElement() {
        var current = $(".curr-str");
        $(current).next('li').addClass('curr-str').fadeOut(5000, function() {
            body.one("click", removeListElement);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.curr-str {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="curr-str">JavaScript</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```